# Multiselect form in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm attempting to add a multi-select widget to my admin view that corresponds to a char-field.

**models.py**

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    budget = models.IntegerField()
    target = models.IntegerField()
    component_choices = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class CampaignAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Main', {
            'fields': ('name', ('start_date', 'end_date',),),
        }),
        ('Budget', {
            'fields': ('budget', 'target',),
        }),
        ('Payment', {
            'fields': ('payment_terms', 'payment_initial', 'payment_per_mvm'),
        }),
    )

    form = ComponentChoicesForm

admin.site.register(Campaign, CampaignAdmin)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ComponentChoicesForm(ModelForm):

    component_type_choices = tuple(
        (x.id, str(x))
        for x in ComponentType.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ComponentType
        fields = '__all__'

    available_components = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=component_type_choices)
```

However the above code only displays the `fieldsets` and not the `ComponentTypeChoices` form at all. My intent is to have the user select from the choices i generate in `forms.py` in the `admin.py` in order to populate the `Campaign.component_choices` field.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a form for a different model and used it in Campaign model admin. You should create a modelform for `Campaign` model rather than `ComponentType`.

Your forms and model admin should be like this,

forms.py

```
class CampaignForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = '__all__'

    OPTIONS = (('a', 'A'),('b', 'B'),('c', 'C'))

    available_components = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                     choices=OPTIONS)
```

admin.py

```
class CampaignAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CampaignForm
```

Comment: this did not work, i'm still not seeing any widget in the admin view

Comment: change your model to Campaign in Meta function.

Comment: Yeah I’ve tried that too. I think fieldsets overrides custom forms. So I’ve gotta write in my fieldsets into a form